# How to make it so that each change change option is written on a new line

Tags: python

```
my_file = open("Data.txt", "w+")
    Data="Hi"
    next_line="\n"
    my_file.write(Data)
    my_file.write(next_line)
    my_file.close()
```

Imagine that the data variable will change its value when the program is running

Comment: I don't understand what you're asking. When `Data` changes, is `my_file` still open, or closed like @J_cyber is suggesting in their answer? If it's closed, have you considered keeping it open? If it's open, what's the problem? Please [edit] to clarify, and please mention what you're trying to accomplish exactly: show us some example data, desired output, and actual output. See [mre]. Also, please clarify the title, cause "change change" seems to be a typo and I'm not sure what "change option" is referring to. BTW, welcome to Stack Overflow! Check out the [tour], and [ask] for more tips.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of opening the file in write mode, you can open it in append mode using 'a'.

```py
def add_change(addition):
    with open("Data.txt",'a') as f:
        f.write(addition+"\n")


add_change("new")
```

Also, by opening the file using  `with open("Data.txt")` means that you don't need to worry about having to close the file with `file.close()`
as this is dealt with already.

The 'a' works by inserting text at the current file stream position which (by default) is at the end of the file.